# How to get Parse.com PUSH registration device token in Phonegap on iOS

Tags: javascript, cordova, push-notification, parse-platform, devicetoken

I am using the Parse PUSH api to integrate PUSH notifications into my iOS app built on Phonegap. I am trying to figure out how to access the device token that is given back by parse. Is there an easy way to do this? Is there a plugin for this already?

Comment: you shouldn't need a plugin, are you just talking about the deviceToken in the Installation object? Once the device is registered for push you should be able to access that just like any other object.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the deviceToken. The Parse SDK is an iOS SDK though and I'm trying to access the deviceToken in Javascript in my Phonegap app.

Comment: Well, you follow the instructions on parse.com to add the iOS SDK to your PhoneGap app (just like a native one, and the instructions are very good) then when the user installs the app, the Installation object gets populated and can then be access like any other Class in parse.com...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279530/how-to-use-parse-push-with-cordova-appcelerator-etc/27279531#27279531

Answer (score 0):

You could use this plugin: https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-push-notification , it worked for me i'm using Phonegap + Parse + this plugin.

Comment: Hey Marcio Just found this. I am currently trying to figure out how to use Parse push notifications with PhoneGap in a IOS app. I am having a look at the plugin you mentioned. I am assuming after you call the register device you are then using the return of that to insert all the data needed into the installation object in Parse? From there you simply use the push javascript sdk to look up tokens and send to them?

Comment: I don't use the javascript sdk, i simply make ajax calls to register the device to get the token, after that it's very simple to whatever you want using the rest api. If you want i can post it my code :)