# Android GCM notifications fail from PubNub, Parse, Amazon SNS

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pubnub

I have been trying to send push notifications to a Phonegap app deployed on iOS and Android. iOS works fine, but Android doesn't work when I send push notifications from any of the dev consoles from PubNub, Parse and Amazon SNS.

I did verify that I can send notifications if I use the GCM API, so I am using the correct Sender ID, API key and the device token.

I don't see any errors on PubNub console. On Parse dashboard I see that the push notifications have been sent. No error on Amazon SNS. Yet, no push notifications on the device.

I am out of ideas. Thanks in advance for any helpful advice.

Comment: To start, I would analyze the adb logcat output when its working, and when you try from a 3rd party... see if there are any glarying differences or log warning/errors...

Comment: Hi Geremy. Pardon my ignorance about Android(been using it for just 2 weeks now). I installed a terminal app on the device. I also installed aLogcat. I don't see any logs when I send notifications in both the situations. I did notice an error when I installed catlog, that it did not have root access. Any ideas how to go from here?

Comment: I don't use Parse/PubNub/SNS, but in using only GCM, your server should receive a response code for every message it sends to your devices. It could give hints as to what errors have occurred.

Comment: Koh, Using GCM works just fine, but for my use case PubNub and Parse would add significant value, and Parse/PubNub send a success response.

Comment: I see. You could also check your Google Developers Console for any statistics that could be helpful: On your project page, go to APIs & auth -> APIs -> Usage.

Comment: Koh, I did look at the statistics page earlier. That confused me even more. I know for sure that I had sent messages directly using GCM but the statistics show 0 for the past week, which can't be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from PubNub, figured out what the issue was. The sample on PubNub has the following format

```
{"pn_gcm": {
    "data" : {
        "GCMSays" : "hi" }
    }
}
```

But the required format was

```
{"pn_gcm": {
        "data" : {
            "message" : "hi" }
        }
 }
```

After confirming using PubNub console, I updated my JSON object in the code and it all worked like a charm.

With Parse console, I tried to create a JSON object with similar format, but it didn't work. Haven't tried Amazon SNS.

Comment: Yes, GCM is looking for the "message" key.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial illustrates how to configure Android GCM with PubNub: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/android/tutorial/google-push-notification.html

Comment: Thanks Geremy. I indeed followed those instructions. I am working with folks from PubNub to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Parse developer] Parse doesn't provide 1st party support for PhoneGap; their product just works with the JS SDK, which doesn't have native Push support. I describe what is necessary to get Parse to recognize your device for push in an arbitrary language [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279530/how-to-use-parse-push-with-cordova-appcelerator-etc/27279531#27279531). You may however be receiving the push but not creating a notification.

In Android (unlike iOS, WinRT, or WinPhone), push doesn't necessarily imply "notification." The native android SDK from Parse [creates this automatically for you](http://blog.parse.com/2014/09/30/android-push-gets-major-refresh/). You'll need to create your own BroadcastReceiver and wire it to handle the intents that the Play Store app is sending for pushes. You can find these in our [Android Push Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications). In your BroadcastReceiver, you'll want to create and register your own Notification object when receiving a push.

Answer (score 0):

For Firebase Cloud Messaging, I had to use this structure to receive a tray notification:

```
"pn_gcm": {
    "notification": {
        "title": push_title,
        "text": push_message
    }
},
```